# Find Average Sales Amount Per Customer T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum, aggregate, average

**I am following a tutorial for T-SQL. My task is to find the total amount per customer and the avarage amount per customer. My solution is the following -**

```
SELECT o.custid, SUM(d.unitprice*d.qty) AS TotalPerCustID, AVG(d.unitprice*d.qty) as AvarageSalesAmount
FROM Sales.Orders as o
INNER JOIN Sales.OrderDetails as d ON
o.orderid=d.orderid
GROUP BY o.custid
ORDER BY o.custid
```

**The result that I get is correct for exactly 12 orders per custid = '1' -**

| custid | TotalPerCustID | AverageSalesAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4596.20 | 383.0166 |

**However, the tutorial is suggesting that the right solution is the following -**

```
SELECT
    c.custid,
    SUM(c.totalsalesamountperorder) AS totalsalesamount,
    AVG(c.totalsalesamountperorder) AS avgsalesamount
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        o.custid, o.orderid, SUM(d.unitprice * d.qty) AS totalsalesamountperorder
    FROM Sales.Orders AS o 
    INNER JOIN Sales.OrderDetails d ON d.orderid = o.orderid
    GROUP BY o.custid, o.orderid
) AS c
GROUP BY c.custid
```

**The result of this solution is, according to my opiniont wrong -**

| custid | totalsalesamount | avgsalesamount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4596.20 | 766.0333 |

**Please advise if there is a difference in the two solutions and which one is the correct one.
Thank you.**

Comment: For the Avg count is matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their query looks correct. Issue is your average(which is sum/count) is wrong because you are using the wrong count. You are using the count of order details, not count of orders. They work around this by first rolling up by orderID, then applying their AVG aggregate.

If you want do it without the sub-select, I'd change your query to calculate the average like so:

```
SELECT SUM(d.UnitPrice*d.Qty)/COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID) AS AverageSalesAmount
```

Comment: Yes, you are totally right! Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: No problem, please mark my answer as accepted so others know your question has been answered

Comment: Hi Stephan, I marked it as accepted √ and it helped all of our group learners here in Skopje :-) We are thankful a lot!